# Read string line-by-line (in Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string, stringbuilder, readline

What is a fast and simple way to read a string line-by-line?

I am currently using Xcode, although solutions in any language are welcome.

For reference, I would prefer to make a function that allows me to read it much like one could read lines from a file in C#:

```
lineString = handle.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Xcode is not a language - it's just an IDE - it supports programming in numerous languages, such as Objective C, Objective C++, C, C++, asm, etc.

Comment: @Paul R: Good point. However, I never implied that Xcode is a language. Nevertheless, I have changed the title according to your suggestion. ;-)

Comment: it was the line: "I am currently using Xcode, although solutions in any language are welcome." which prompted my comment. ;-)

Comment: @Paul R: Hehe, I understood. Ok, for purism: _Technically_, it does not claim that Xcode is a language. I simply state that I welcome suggestions in any languge, even though I am using Xcode (which might lead people to believe that I am only looking for C/Objective-C code). But ok... let's focus on a solution :-) I appreciate your comments!

Answer (score 2):

The answer does not explain how to read a **LARGE** text file line by line. There is not nice solution in Objective-C for reading large text files without putting them into memory (which isn't always an option).

In these case I like to use the c methods:

```
FILE* file = fopen("path to my file", "r");

size_t length;
char *cLine = fgetln(file,&length);

while (length>0) {
    char str[length+1];
    strncpy(str, cLine, length);
    str[length] = '\0';

    NSString *line = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",str];        
    % Do what you want here.

    cLine = fgetln(file,&length);
}
```

Note that fgetln will not keep your newline character. Also, We +1 the length of the str because we want to make space for the NULL termination.